# Continuing list item after sublist in Lyx

Tags: lists, lyx

I'm trying to continue a list item after existing a sublist, like so:

- Content

  1. sublist
  2. sublist

  Continuing CONTENT...
- bla bla

For some reason when trying to write the Continuing CONTENT 
I either had the option to continue the list (as in - creating another sublist item) or creating another list item (like bla bla) 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly possible. You just have to switch the paragraph type of the unwanted "3." enum item back to "Standard" to continue an item of an enclosing list:

[image: screen shot]

Here is the code that LyX 2.0 generates out of this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Content

\begin{enumerate}
\item sublist
\item sublist
\end{enumerate}

Continuing CONTENT

\item bla bla
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the created itemize you can go with the TAB key into a deeper one and with the SHIFT TAB key into a higher level. After "2. sublist" insert SHIFT TAB and then you are on the first level but with a new bullet. Then click on the default paragraph icon and you are in the normal paragraph mode. Now hit TAB again and you can write on the same level.

Comment: _If you want to continue without a bullet you have to use the TeX mode to insert the deeper level of itemize._ @Herbert: That is not true (even though badly documented), see my answer.

Comment: _Then hit again SHIFT TAB and you are in the normal paragraph mode. Now hit TAB again and you can write on the same level._ @Herbert: Have you tested this? At least with Mac LyX 2.0.1 it does not work (SHIFT TAB does not get you back in normal paragraph mode).

Comment: you are right, SHIFT TAB works only if you want back from the level without a bullet to paragraph mode