# Resume writing in a lower list nesting level

Tags: lyx, lists, enumerate

Having this "simple" problem, but can't find any solution to it. Probably a duplicate, but didn't find it either.

Suppose I'm writing a list about numbers:

```
1. One is the first positive integer
2. Here are examples of things that come in pairs of two:
    - eyes
    - arms
    - legs
   btw, 2 is the first prime.
3. IDK what to say about three here. hello.
```

but this always refuses to render properly. In LyX the only manipulation I can achieve is:

1. One is the first positive integer
2. Here are examples of things that come in pairs of two:

   - eyes
   - arms
   - legs
3. btw, 2 is the first prime.
4. IDK what to say about three here. hello.

as in, it inserts an extra list entry where I wanted to go back to talking about 2.
Funnily, on this website it renders like this:

1. One is the first positive integer
2. Here are examples of things that come in pairs of two:

   - eyes
   - arms
   - legs
     btw, two is the first prime.
3. IDK what to say about three here. hello.

which is somehow even worse, and also the reason I had to use a block comment there.

Unsurprisingly, this is not much different when using numbered/bullet lists. The only solution I found was with the enumItem package and it wasn't clean at all:

Surround the whole list in another context, stylised so it appears the same as text inside the list. Get to the point where you want to exit into the previous nest level, and exit to the outside context instead. Type whatever goes after the inner list, then start a new enumeration that resumes the previous one. I want to believe this is the wrong way, but I didn't find a single example of the "right" way anywhere online.

Comment: May be one of those (or all) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/continuing-list-item-after-sublist-in-lyx/34081#34081  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177214/lyx-itemize-returning-to-last-number/178636#178636  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374260/in-lyx-how-can-i-nest-itemize-inside-enumerate-without-starting-a-new-enumerat/374375#374375

Comment: thanks. this can be safely closed as duplicate of one of those, probably the last as it is most informative. fsr I don't see a button to do it myself, either low on points, blind, or shitty mobile UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In LyX, how can I nest Itemize inside Enumerate, without starting a new Enumerate item when leaving Itemize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374260/in-lyx-how-can-i-nest-itemize-inside-enumerate-without-starting-a-new-enumerat)

Comment: I think you can also close yourself (flag → duplicate → paste question link → refresh page → click the "close" button), if there's a flag button at all.